# SQL Query to execute in a loop

Tags: oracle10g

I need your help with the following query.

```
SELECT
 SQL_ID,
 SNAP_ID,
 EXECUTIONS_TOTAL,
 EXECUTIONS_DELTA,
 CPU_TIME_TOTAL,
 CPU_TIME_DELTA,
 ELAPSED_TIME_TOTAL,
 ELAPSED_TIME_DELTA
from
 WRH$_SQLSTAT
where
 SQL_ID='807mzfr04qt1c' and
 SNAP_ID in (19507,19508);
```

I have to execute the above query every hour to get the results(the snap_id value changes to 19508-19509 in next hour from 19507-19508). Let us say for an entire day the begin snap id started from 19507 and ended in 19530. I would need help in writing a script that should execute it from the start id(19507) and compare it with the next id(19508) and the next id(19508) becomes the start id and so on and thus execute until the end id(19530) is reached.

Answer (score 0):

You could use DBMS_SCHEDULER. for your version of oracle 10g. I am bit confused where are u trying to implement it in SQL or ORACLE, cause ur question is tagged in oracle 10g and u have mentioned your question with SQL.

But if you are using **oracle 10g** u can achieve it by using **DBMS_SCHEDULER**, incase you are uing some other version **v7.3.4 to 9i oracle**, use **DBMS_JOB** to schedule a task.

If u are using **MS SQL Server** us can achieve this by **creating scheduled jobs**. In SQL Management Studio, navigate to the server, then expand the SQL Server Agent item, and finally the Jobs folder to view, edit, add scheduled jobs.